# YouTube upload API - Get Auth tokens for offline

Tags: c#, .net, youtube, youtube-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have working a video upload working using the .net samples code.

But I cannot seem to find a way to get the returned auth codes so they can be saved in my database. I understand you can specify the FileDataStore object, but how can I get the raw values?

I'm pretty surprised googles api's are so convoluted, seems such a simple task

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

"convoluted"  that's so harsh :/   But I think you mean

> I'm pretty surprised googles .Net client library is so convoluted, seems such a simple task

This really has nothing to do with the API in general its the client library you are having a problem with.

See code: service would be your authenticated YouTubeService.

```
var RefreshToken= ((UserCredential)service.HttpClientInitializer).Token.RefreshToken;
```

Note: feature request for adding a method to get this.  [[Auth] getRefreshToken() method #697](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/697)